# Wamp Server showing Syntax Error widthout any actual Error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I created a simple php script for uploading data to a MySQL server using wamp.
My script is -

```
<?php
    $server = "127.22.9.0";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "complaints";

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {  // This is that line 9
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    echo "Connected successfully";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO complaints (email, title, details) VALUES ('".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['dtls']."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
?>
```

When I execute this on wamp server, it shows an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 9
```

I have thoroughly searched for errors but found nothing.

Can anyone help me in this?

**EDIT: I solved my problem but in an unusual way -**

I retyped my code and removed some unnecessary spaces and changed the structure of if statement. Now, my code works -

```
$server = "127.22.9.0";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "complaints";

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);

nl2br($_POST['dtls']);

if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Error: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO complaints (email, title, details) VALUES ('".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['title']."', '".$_POST['dtls']."')";

if($conn->query($sql))
{
    echo "<h1>Success!! Your complaint has been successfully registered!!</h1>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

The changes are quite unnecessary but it works.

Comment: $conn->connect_error show error because this is mysqli method use  $conn->connect_error()

Comment: I added that. Now it shows error on `die` `syntax error, unexpected 'die' (T_EXIT) in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 10`

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: the version is php 5.6.25

Comment: check your local IP 127.1.1.0

Comment: this shows the same error

Comment: @pawansen It shows error on the second if statement, after removing the first if statement

Comment: is connect_error a function? If it is, it needs parenthesis at the end.

Comment: try to use procedural style@Aneesh

Answer (score -1):

```
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $db);
if (!$conn) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: use above code their version prob with your code@Aneesh

Comment: You are mixing `OOP` and `procedural` style.

Comment: There is a [correct way to make a MYSQLI connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) and test if it has connected, and the OP is using it. This is definitely not it!

Comment: please explain a bit.

Comment: this is procedural style @Xorifelse

Comment: $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. If you need to ensure compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0 then use my code